# Flyway migration not working with gradle

Tags: sql, gradle, flyway

I'm trying to migrate some SQL tables using the gradle script:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.boxfuse.client:flyway-release:4.0.3'
    classpath group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4.1208.jre7'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'

flyway {
  user = 'postgres'
  url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test'
  driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
  locations = ['filesystem:scripts']
}
```

And in the **scripts** directory I have just one SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE place (
  id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  country VARCHAR(255),
  country_code VARCHAR(255),
  name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

When I run `gradle flywayMigrate -i` I get the output:

```
Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test (PostgreSQL 9.5)
Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.009s)
Current version of schema "public": << Empty Schema >>
Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

In the **test database** the **schema_version** table is created, but the table **place** is not.

The directory structure for flyway is:

```
flyway-dir
  -- build.gradle
  -- scripts/001-add_place_table.sql
```

Am I missing some additional settings for flyway? It's quite unfortunate the I don't get any error message.

Comment: It looks correctly, what is: **operational-db**  directory? You mention it once only.

Comment: @Opal: Sorry, I wrote the wrong name for the scripts directory. I've edited the mistake.

Comment: It also seems that you the wrong script name, please investigate _Naming_ section: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/sql

Comment: The naming convention was the problem. Can you please write an answer so I can vote it as the correct one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you've that the migration script is named incorrectly. Please name the script appropriately - [see *Naming* section](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#naming).

Comment: __(2 underscores) should be noted